# Is grace a person?

Tags: john, jesus, grace

In John 1:17

> ..  grace and truth came through Jesus Christ.

So we know that graces came through Jesus. Joseph Prince goes as far as to say that when Jesus talks about grace, He is talking about Himself, that grace is a person, that grace is Jesus Himself.

How serious should we take that claim?

Comment: Jesus is the prime example of Grace but the NT NEVER says that Jesus IS grace.  The closest we come is where 1 John 4:8, 16, says that God is love.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For ***the grace of God*** that bringeth salvation ***hath appeared*** to all men, Teaching us that, denying ungodliness and worldly lusts, we should live soberly, righteously, and godly, in this present world;  [Titus 2:11,12 KJV]

I have quoted the above text as it may be that which has suggested the question, originally.

Here, Paul says that grace has 'appeared' but not to just some, to everyone. If so, then an appearance has ministered grace to the whole world.

But that appearance teaches. And what it teaches is that we should deny ungodliness and worldly lusts. And we should live a life of sobriety, righteousness and godliness.

My own understanding of this text is that the coming of the Son of God, in person, has brought an appearing of grace to the whole world. But he is not alone. With him is an influence, which is another person. That other person is Holy.

And the influence of that other person causes the effects that Paul describes.

There is an element of truth in what prompted the question. But two persons are involved, not one. And yet there is another, for 'the Father sent the Son to be the saviour of the world', 1 John 4:14.

Answer (score 1):

You won’t find any verse or scripture that directly says this. (That Grace is a person/Jesus.). But, nevertheless, in a similar vein to ‘the trinity’, scripture clearly shows this.

The clouding issue is the definition or interpretation of **the word** ‘Grace’, in particular as it is used in doctrinal statements. But, putting these aside, and looking at scripture, it is clear that what Joseph Prince says can easily be seen.

How do we have access to grace? Through a person. We say that by Grace we are saved. Well, how are we saved? Through the finished work of Jesus. Through his life, obedience, death and resurrection. What is our faith ‘in’, whose is our faith? Jesus. Grace is either what you ‘see’ in your heart, or, what you reason in your head. One is a person, the other is a ‘force’ or ‘empowerment’. And, what you ‘see’ in your heart is what many call revelation.

Grace is what is provided through the finished work of the cross. And we only have access to this in Jesus.

Comment: "clearly shows this" do you mean that grace is a person or that the Scriptures show trinity or both?

Comment: Yes, scripture clearly reveals Grace is a person. (But, also true that scripture clearly lets us see God as three persons.)

Answer (score 0):

Grace is not a person. Grace, in the Bible sense, is unmerited favor and kindness freely bestowed by God upon unworthy and undeserving people.

Ephesians 2:8-9

> <sup>**8**</sup> For by grace you have been saved through faith, and that not of yourselves; it is the gift of God, <sup>**9**</sup> not of works, lest anyone should boast.

Paul emphasizes that salvation comes via grace and defines grace as a gift that is unearned. While it is true that we could not be saved were it not for the redemption provided by Jesus, it is also true that Jesus would not have come except it was for the grace of God the Father.

Titus 2:11

> For the grace of God that brings salvation has appeared to all men

If you are to say that grace is a person (Jesus) then Titus 2:11 states that Jesus has appeared to all men. It seems Titus is truly saying that God's grace in giving His Son makes salvation available to all people.

John 1:14-17

> <sup>**14**</sup> And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we beheld His glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father, full of grace and truth. <sup>**15**</sup> John bore witness of Him and cried out, saying, "This was He of whom I said, 'He who comes after me is preferred before me, for He was before me.'" <sup>**16**</sup> And of His fullness we have all received, and grace for grace. <sup>**17**</sup> For the law was given through Moses, but grace and truth came through Jesus Christ.

John states that Jesus is **full of grace** not that He **is** grace. John also states that grace came through Jesus. If you say that grace is a person, then you must think John is saying that Jesus (grace) came through Jesus Christ.

In the same passage, it says that truth also came through Jesus. Jesus didn't say that He was truth. He said that was "**the** Truth" in John 14:6.

It is true that Jesus is the epitome of grace. He exemplifies grace and is "full of grace". It appears that some preachers say that grace is a person (Jesus) in order to try to simplify to their listeners this concept. However, this can bring confusion when reading other Scripture about grace. If one were to try to substitute the idea that "grace is Jesus" into other passages, it would not hold up to accurate Bible interpretation. We are exhorted to extend grace to each other which simply means we are to show kindness and favor even if they don't deserve it. In essence, we are to treat others the same way Jesus treated us when He extended grace to us.

As a previous answer states, "You won’t find any verse or scripture that directly says that Grace is a person/Jesus." Let the Word of God be your guide in interpreting Scripture and please be like the Bereans who always searched the Scriptures for truth after listening to a speaker.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).